# htaccess mod-rewrite anchor

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**I have this url:** `mysite.com/account/user#editSucc`, **I want it to be parsed as** `mysite.com?goTo=account&section=user&msg=editSucc`.

This is my **.htaccess file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^account/([A-Za-z-]+)$ /?goTo=account&section=$1 [L,NC]
```

How can I make the part with the `#` symbol? and merge it with the existing code?
Thanks.

Comment: @hjpotter92 This question refers to adding a rule to expand an existing one

Comment: That doesn’t change anything about what the accepted answer says.

Comment: @Xriuk: Text after `#` is only handled by browser hence web server will only get URI like `mysite.com/account/user`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using htaccess. The URL fragment (everything after `#`) is **never** sent to the server and thus nothing on the server's end even knows it exists. You need a strictly client side solution to deal with it. Since you want it to be redirected (and that's all you'll be able to do with it). you can try something like [from this link](http://stephenmcintyre.net/blog/fragment-anchor-php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var parts = location.href.split('#');
if(parts.length > 1)
{
    location.href = '/?goTo=account&section=user&msg=' + parts[1];
}
```